# save multiple pentagons as image at each step of for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib

I need to save 4 pentagons as image at each step but it saves each image on the previous one. I need each image include one separate polygon.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pixels = 600
my_dpi = 100
num_geo=3

coord = np.array([[[-150, -200], [300, -200], [300, 0], [150, 200], [-150, 200]],
                  [[-300, -200], [200, -300], [200, -50], [200, 300], [-150, 200]],
                  [[-140, -230], [350, -260], [350, 0], [140, 200], [-180, 220]],
                  [[-180, -240], [370, -270], [370, 0], [170, 200], [-190, 230]]])


fig = plt.figure(num_geo,figsize=( pixels/my_dpi,  pixels/my_dpi),facecolor='k', dpi=my_dpi)  


plt.axes([0,0,1,1])

rectangle = plt.Rectangle((-300, -300), 600, 600, fc='k')
plt.gca().add_patch(rectangle)



for i in range(4):

    geo = coord[i, :, :]
    print(coord[i])

    polygon = plt.Polygon(coord[i],color='w')
    plt.gca().add_patch(polygon)
    plt.savefig('figure/%d.jpg' % i, dpi=my_dpi)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.axis([-300,300,-300,300])
i =+ 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the figure and the background rectangle inside the for loop and then close the plot using `plt.close()` at the end of the loop. If you do not close the plot the same axis will be used to plot the new polygon. Here's your code with minor adjustments:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pixels = 600
my_dpi = 100
num_geo=3

coord = np.array([[[-150, -200], [300, -200], [300, 0], [150, 200], [-150, 200]],
                  [[-300, -200], [200, -300], [200, -50], [200, 300], [-150, 200]],
                  [[-140, -230], [350, -260], [350, 0], [140, 200], [-180, 220]],
                  [[-180, -240], [370, -270], [370, 0], [170, 200], [-190, 230]]])

for i in range(4):
    geo = coord[i, :, :]
    print(coord[i])
    fig = plt.figure(num_geo,figsize=( pixels/my_dpi,  pixels/my_dpi),facecolor='k', dpi=my_dpi)  
    plt.axes([0,0,1,1])
    rectangle = plt.Rectangle((-300, -300), 600, 600, fc='k')
    plt.gca().add_patch(rectangle)
    polygon = plt.Polygon(coord[i],color='w')
    plt.gca().add_patch(polygon)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.axis([-300,300,-300,300])
    plt.savefig('figure/%d.jpg' % i, dpi=my_dpi)
    plt.close()
```

---

Here's a slightly more pythonic way to write the for loop, which uses the object style of matplotlib. This way you don't need to close the figure since a new figure and a new axis are created at the beginning of the loop:

```
for index, c in enumerate(coord):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=( pixels/my_dpi, pixels/my_dpi), dpi=my_dpi)  
    rectangle = plt.Rectangle((-300, -300), 600, 600, fc='k')
    ax.add_patch(rectangle)
    polygon = plt.Polygon(c, color='w')
    ax.add_patch(polygon)
    ax.axis('off')
    ax.axis([-300,300,-300,300])
    fig.savefig('figure/%d.jpg' % index, dpi=my_dpi)
```

Comment: You could also just use `plt.clf()` - you don’t necessarily have to close the figure or create a whole new one each time, you can reuse it as long as it gets cleared each iteration

Comment: Yes, this is indeed another possibility